# How to read from non-default bucket in google cloud storage in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

This document [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) says "Note that if you don't use the default bucket, you'll need some other way to supply the bucket name."  How do you supply the non-default bucket?

I know how to use gfile to read any bucket using the "`gs://<bucket_name>//file` syntax but this is a different api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for the `open` method:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open

> **Arguments**
>
> > filename (REQUIRED) The file to open, in the format **/bucket/object**.

The format you need to supply to the api is
`"/<bucket_name>/<file>"`

For example: `"/my_bucket/lyrics/southamerica/list5.txt"`

This is the GitHub reference to the `open` method
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py#L47-L54

Comment: Not a problem :-)